# Hyperlink in email can't display normally in outlook 2003

Tags: outlook, outlook-2003

I am developing a project to send email. The email is stored in html format as a template. I use that template and replace necessary fields in html, then send it by a component.

The hyperlink in the email displays as plain text in Outlook 2003, but it is a hyperlink in Outlook 2007.

Comment: Could you please paste an example, including the `<HTML>` and `<head>` code. Cheers

Comment: I have solved this case.

Outlook2007 will  generate hyperlink for string which contains "http://" or "@hotmail.com" etc. automatically. However,Outlook2003 will not.

So, my source code is incorrect at the very start. I should given it a "<a></a>" container beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

"I have solved this case. Outlook2007 will generate hyperlink for string which contains "http://" or "@hotmail.com" etc. automatically. However,Outlook2003 will not. So, my source code is incorrect at the very start. I should given it a "" container beforehand. –  [Domi.N.Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676029/domi-n-zhang) Mar 26 '11 at 1:01"

Comment: Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.